# JQueryUI window not covering all content elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a task at work where I must implement a simple browser-based chat system for an intranet. Backend is ready, and now I'm trying to create the UI part but it's giving me a big headache, and been banging my head against the desk for hours because of this :(

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2PMvM/ (it uses JQuery + JQueryUI - 1.x)

The HTML, semantically, looks right, but it doesn't work as good as it looks. The idea is that the window (red border div) should contain all of its elements. I don't know why the list's horizontal scrollbar and then my textarea get out of the window, as if there's some offset I'm not taking into account?

I'm trying to do this with the least JS possible, but if the CSS way is too complicated, I'm willing to take a JS solution then.

What could be wrong though?. Thanks in advance :)

--- SO requires me to put the code, so here it goes:

Note: be sure to include this JS: https://github.com/AndrewDryga/jQuery.Textarea.Autoresize/raw/master/js/jquery.textarea.autoresize.js because it is required so my textarea autosizes when it gets more text. The window should contain the textarea even if it resizes. Seems like CSS could do it, but no?

**IT IS SOLVED!! Thanks to @Trevor:**  Here's the updated code + Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/YyX9D/1/). Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="window">    
<div style="height: 20px;" class="wndHandle">Some username :D</div>
<div class="content" id="chatDiv" style="background:#fff;overflow: scroll;">
    <ul class="ulChat">
        <li class="msg in">Test message for testing 1</li>
        <li class="msg out">Test message for testing 2</li>
        <li class="msg out">Test message for testing 3</li>
        <li class="msg in">Test message for testing 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <textarea style="width: 100%; resize: none; overflow-x: hidden;" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-resizable-handle 
{
    background: #f5dc58; border: 1px solid #FFF;
    width: 9px; height: 9px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.ui-resizable-se { right: -5px; bottom: -5px; }

.window
{
    position: absolute; 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;   
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;   
}

.wndHandle {
    cursor: move;
    font-size: 9pt;
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var refresh = function() {
    var objWindow = $('.window');
    var objHandle = objWindow.find('.wndHandle');
    var objContent = objWindow.find('.content');
    var objFooter = objWindow.find('.footer');
    var objResize = objWindow.find(".ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-se");
    objResize.removeClass("ui-resizable-autohide");
    objContent.height(
        objWindow.innerHeight() -
        objHandle.outerHeight() -
        (
            (objFooter.length == 0) ?
            (objResize.length == 0) ? 0 : objResize.outerHeight()
            : objFooter.outerHeight()
        )
    );
}

$('.window').draggable({ handle: '.wndHandle' }).resizable({
    handles: 'se',
    minWidth: 150,
    minHeight: 100,
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
        refresh();
    }
});

$('textarea').autoresize({
    maxHeight: 80,
    onResize: function () {
        refresh();
    }    
});

refresh();
```

Comment: the middle div has `height:100%`, so the total height (including the first div's height and the textarea's height) will be larger than 100%, hence your problem. I think you should set the `height` for the textarea explicitly so that you can use `calc()` or absolute layout to fit them correctly. I know you want to set the height of textarea so that it can just show 1 line (`rows=1`), that means the height depends on the font-size and also maybe the line-height, so it's some kind of dynamic. Solving this problem with dynamic requirement is not easy, unless use Flex Box layout.

Comment: Well, that middle div has `height: 100%` because I dunno. It seemed right to put it there since in my mind I want it to be 100% of the -available- height, not total window height. I get your point. I've seen flexbox, but I don't like it at all. I assume a JS solution would work? calculating the 100% UL div's height minus the window handle and textarea size? :/. I don't know what to put there, I just want the window to contain all its elements, I don't know if the `height: 100%` should be there or not :(

Comment: here you see in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/2PMvM/26/ , we use `calc()` method to set the height for the middle div. Note that to change the font-size of the textarea, you have to change the `font-size` of `.window` instead, then decrease the font-size on the handle and the `.ulChat`. That's the only simple way to go for dynamic requirement.

Comment: i tried, but this is as far as i got. sorry i couldnt be of more help. http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/2PMvM/34/

Comment: Don't worry, your solution along with @Trevor's helped me to reach a working one. I've updated the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using jQuery to adjust the height

HTML - added ID

```
...
<div id="chatDiv" style="background:#fff;overflow: scroll;">
...
```

jQuery

```
$('.window').draggable({ handle: '.wndHandle' }).resizable({
    handles: 'se',
    minWidth: 150,
    minHeight: 100,
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#chatDiv').height($('.window').height()-38);          
    }
});
$('#chatDiv').height($('.window').height()-38);
$('textarea').autoresize();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YyX9D/)

Comment: Big thanks @Trevor !! :D your solution actually helped me to figure out how to calculate what I need, and I even converted it into a simple plugin for my system :) later today or tomorrow, I will update the OP with a JSFiddle with the working code, also integrating the textarea resizing. Works wonderfully!